# Why in aromatic nucleophilic substitution the Nucleophile attacks carbon and not the halogen?

Tags: organic-chemistry

In nucleophilic aromatic substitution of halobenzene why does Nucleophile attack the carbon atom bonded to halide X not the halide.

The carbon atom atom has partial positive charge whereas the halide has positive charge due to resonance as its lone pair is delocalised in the benzene ring doesn't resonance always dominate so why does Nucleophile behave so?

I can think of because of lone pair repulsions between electron rich Nucleophile and halogen but I'm not sure. May someone help ? 
(Ofcourse Here the benzene ring has electron withdrawing groups at o p position)

Comment: Your argument applies to every other nucleophilic substitution reaction, yet they all don't proceed that way. Therefore, what other factors are more important?

Comment: I dont know. What are you saying ?

Comment: First I'm saying that you're looking at the wrong factors because they also don't work to explain anything else. Second, I'm saying that should consider transition state stabilization because that really governs whether or not these reactions proceed at all.

Comment: Yeah I know that. Im asking why these factors are wrong and dont explain anything else ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this question. These are statements, but I don't see what they have to do with understanding the mechanism of an ipso attack...